# Weakest preconditions for higher order recursive function

Tags: dafny

I am trying to play around with partial functions and higher order functions in Dafny. I wrote `funpow(n,f,t)` that apply the function `f` `n` times to the value `t`.

```
function funpow<T(!new)>(n:nat, f: T ~> T,t: T): T
requires forall i :: 0 <= i < n ==> f.requires(funpow(i,f,t))
reads f.reads
decreases n
{
  if n == 0
  then t
  else f(funpow(n-1,f,t))
}
```

I would like to express the most general precondition `forall i :: 0 <= i < n ==> f.requires(funpow(i,f,t))` and Dafny does not like this.

The issue above is that we need to show Dafny that `funpow.requires(i,f,t)` is satisfied when calling `funpow(i,f,t)`. I changed it to `forall i :: 0 <= i < n ==> funpow.requires(i,f,t) && f.requires(funpow(i,f,t))`, and now I got `Error: cannot use naked function in recursive setting. Possible solution: eta expansion.`

I then tried `n > 0 ==> funpow.requires(n-1,f,t) && f.requires(funpow(n-1,f,t))` as the precondition.  I got the naked function error again.

I then lookup the reference manual and found that there is an `{:autoReq}` flag that generate the precondition automatically. However, it does not seem to handle recursion.

I am currently using dafny version 3.7.1 .

How should I make this work?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly the way `funpow` is written it should be able to call `f` with any `t` (as `t` is one of parameter and there is no prerequisite on `t` and I can just set `n` to 2)

Then why not add this as require ```requires forall s : T :: f.requires(s)``` or make it total

Comment: The idea is you can apply f n times as long as it stays in the domain of f. Given any t, there is a restriction on n. The reason why I didn't want to put a trivial precondition or make it total is mainly just out of curiosity at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solve this problem by using predicate to represent the function as a relation. We can now then use the predicate to express the preconditions that we want.

```
predicate funpow_pred<T(!new)>(n:nat, f: T ~> T,t: T,t':T)
reads f.reads
{
  (n == 0 && t' == t) ||
  (n > 0 && exists t2 :: funpow_pred(n-1,f,t,t2) &&
    f.requires(t2) && f(t2) == t')
}

// uniqueness
lemma funpow_pred_uniq<T(!new)>(n:nat,f: T ~> T, t:T, t1:T, t2:T)
requires funpow_pred(n,f,t,t1)
requires funpow_pred(n,f,t,t2)
ensures t1 == t2
{
  if n == 0
  {
    assert t1 == t;
    assert t2 == t;
  }
  else
  {
    var t3 :| funpow_pred(n-1,f,t,t3);
    forall t4 | funpow_pred(n-1,f,t,t4)
    ensures funpow_pred(n-1,f,t,t4) ==> t4 == t3
    {
      funpow_pred_uniq(n-1,f,t,t3,t4);
    }
    assert t1 == f(t3);
    assert t2 == f(t3);
  }
}

// use the predicates to state the preconditions
function funpow<T(!new)>(n:nat,f:T~>T,t:T): T
reads f.reads
requires n > 0 ==> exists t'' :: funpow_pred(n-1,f,t,t'') && f.requires(t'')
ensures funpow_pred(n,f,t,funpow(n,f,t))
ensures forall t'' :: funpow_pred(n,f,t,t'') ==> t'' == funpow(n,f,t)
{
  if n == 0 then t
  else
    ghost var t'' :| funpow_pred(n-1,f,t,t'') && f.requires(t'');
    funpow_pred_uniq(n-1,f,t,funpow(n-1,f,t),t'');
    assert funpow(n-1,f,t) == t'';
    f(funpow(n-1,f,t))
}

// check that this is exactly what I want
lemma funpow_req_lem<T(!new)>(n:nat,f:T~>T,t:T)
ensures (n > 0 ==> funpow.requires(n-1,f,t) && f.requires(funpow(n-1,f,t))) == funpow.requires(n,f,t)
{
}

predicate inrange(i:nat,n:nat)
{
  0 <= i < n
}

predicate exists_funpow_pred<T(!new)>(i:nat,f: T ~> T, t:T)
reads f.reads
{
  exists t' :: funpow_pred(i,f,t,t') && f.requires(t')
}

lemma funpow_pred_forall<T(!new)>(n:nat, f: T ~> T,t: T, t': T)
requires funpow_pred(n,f,t,t')
ensures forall i {:trigger inrange(i,n)} :: 0 <= i < n ==> exists_funpow_pred(i,f,t)
{
  if n == 0
  {
  }
  else
  {
    forall i | 0 <= i < n
    ensures exists_funpow_pred(i,f,t)
    {
      if i == n - 1
      {
        var t' :| funpow_pred(n-1,f,t,t') && f.requires(t');
        assert funpow_pred(i,f,t,t') && f.requires(t');
      }
      else
      {
        var t' :| funpow_pred(n-1,f,t,t') && f.requires(t');
        funpow_pred_forall(n-1,f,t,t');
        assert inrange(i,n-1);
        assert exists t'' :: funpow_pred(i,f,t,t'') && f.requires(t'');
      }
    }
  }
}

// Validate
function foo(n:int):int
requires n < 2
{
  n + 1
}

method Validator()
{
  assert funpow(0,foo,0) == 0;
  funpow_req_lem(1,foo,0);
  assert funpow(1,foo,0) == 1;
  funpow_req_lem(2,foo,0);
  assert funpow(2,foo,0) == 2;
  assert !foo.requires(2);
}
```

p.s. Making the function total as suggested would make life much easier.

```
datatype option<T> = Some(t:T) | None

function funpow<T(!new)>(n:nat,f:T ~> option<T>,t:T): option<T>
reads f.reads
requires forall x :: f.requires(x) // make it total
{
  if n == 0 then Some(t)
  else
    match funpow(n-1,f,t)
      case Some(y) => f(y)
      case None => None
}
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution. If you're interested I setup a template for Advent of Code this year for Dafny. https://github.com/hath995/Dafny-AoC-template

Answer (score 0):

Using the function funpow in the requires definitely caused that error. You can modify it like this.

```
function funpow<T(!new)>(n:nat, f: T ~> T,t: T, ts: set<T>): T
requires forall tx :: tx in ts ==> f.requires(tx)
requires forall tx :: tx in ts ==> f(tx) in ts
requires t in ts
reads f.reads
ensures funpow(n,f,t,ts) in ts
decreases n
{
  if n == 0
  then t
  else f(funpow(n-1,f,t,ts))
}
```

I see, it's an interesting problem. The following verifies as well.

```
function funpow<T(!new)>(n:nat, f: T ~> T,t: T): T
    reads f.reads
    requires n <=5
    requires f.requires(t)
    requires f.requires(f(t))
    requires f.requires(f(f(t)))
    requires f.requires(f(f(f(t))))
    requires f.requires(f(f(f(f(t)))))
    requires f.requires(f(f(f(f(f(t))))))
    ensures n == 0 ==> funpow(n, f, t) == t
    ensures n == 1 ==> funpow(n, f, t) == f(t)
    ensures n == 2 ==> funpow(n, f, t) == f(f(t))
    ensures n == 3 ==> funpow(n, f, t) == f(f(f(t)))
    decreases n
{
    if n == 0
    then t
    else f(funpow(n-1,f,t))
}
```

I tried to encapsulate it generally like this.

```
ghost predicate iterativePartial<T(!new)>(f: T ~> T, t: T, n: nat) 
    reads f.reads
{
    if n == 0 then f.requires(t) else f.requires(t) && f.requires(f(t)) && iterativePartial(f, f(t), n-1)
}
```

However, it didn't quite verify.

Comment: Thank you. I like the idea to put a set in the argument to limit the domain and codomain. However, this is not too satisfying. If I understand it correctly, essentially it limits the domain of `funpow f` to the intersection the domain of f and the codomain of f. It is not the weakest possible precondition. It loses the ability to call `funpow 2` on an element when applying `f` 3 times would reach something outside the domain of `f`.

Comment: I also am using Dafny 4.3.0 so that may affect verification and syntax.

Comment: It seems like we can use least predicate to express funpow as relation
`least predicate funpow_pred<T(!new)>(n:nat, f: T ~> T,t: T,t':T) reads f.reads {(n == 0 && t' == t) || (n > 0 && exists t2 :: funpow_pred(n-1,f,t,t2) && f.requires(t2) && f(t2) == t')}`. Maybe we can do hilbert choice on it and get the function

Comment: The thing about Dafny is that once you've defined the right predicate pretty much every tends to fall in place. The second thing to think about are triggers. https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ#how-does-dafny-handle-quantifiers-ive-heard-about-triggers-what-are-those